# MaterialUI Tabs not responsive

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tabs

I'm trying to create an appbar with tabs on it and then render it into my page using reactDOM, and it renders fine but clicking on a tab won't change tab for some reason.

What I tried so far:

- printing the value state and checking that it actually changes (it does)
- using the MUI example and seeing if it's a browser thing (it isn't)
- Rendering the appbar, tabs, and tabpanels separately which led to more issues.

Some relevant code:

```
//this code is inside a component
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
};
//json_links is a list of jsons that provides user information
const ListOfTabs = json_links.map((link, index) => (
      <Tab value={index} label={link['userName']} {...a11yProps({index})} />
))
//TabPanel is taken from the material-ui example on tabs
const ListOfTabPanels = json_links.map((link, index) => (
      <TabPanel value={value} index={index}><Profile imagelist={link['images']} username={link['userName']}/></TabPanel>
    ))
let TabsElement = <div><AppBar id="tabsAppBar" position="static"><Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">{ListOfTabs}</Tabs></AppBar>{ListOfTabPanels}</div>
ReactDOM.render(TabsElement, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Expected behavior: users show in different tabs and a click switches users

Actual behavior: users show in different tabs and a click does nothing, it changes the state but the tab elements aren't "notified" of the change and don't respond

Comment: It doesn't appear your useState hook is part of an actual component. Try wrapping your code (minus the last line that renders) inside a functional component (returning TabsElement) then call render using said component. React needs to re-render components after any state changes and I don't see how it can do that if it can't call the useState value each time you make a change

Comment: it actually is, I didn't include the whole code just the parts that probably cause the problems
Everything renders fine but changing the "value" doesn't switch tabs which is the issue

Comment: thanks for the comment tho! I made the question more specific